# Resizing a table by textheight reduces the width

Tags: tables, scaling, paper-size

I have a large table (height does not fit in page) and I use this code in order to fit it in height.

```
\begin{table}[]
\resizebox{!}{0.65\textheight}{
\begin{tabular}{lllll}

...

\end{tabular}}
\end{table}
```

The problem is that the table shrinks also in width. Is it possible to keep the original width of the table but shrink in height in order to fit in page?

I do not want to use some special packages here.

Comment: Rewrite/redesign your table. Resizing like this should never be a solution. Btw you are already using a special package just to get resize box, so what is wrong with other packages?

Comment: Can you provide some details about rewrite/redesign the table? Thank you

Comment: You do not give any details of the contents, so no can do. We just see a lot of new users who grab resizebox every time they get into problems. It might be solved by using a smaller font size, or by going to a table design that allows page breaks. At other times, tables might not even be the best tool for the job.

Comment: you are not really asking to distort the shape of every letter in the table so that it is not readable but fits in the page?????  it is best never to apply scaling to tables.

Comment: Hi @DavidCarlisle, the table fits almost in page. I try to rduce the fonts with \tiny but again the width reduced.

Comment: what is wrong with the width reducing? (it can not possibly be as bad as distorting the fonts)  but you have shown no code, if you have a fixed with table then changing the font size will not change the width.

Comment: If you want specific widths of some columns, instead `{lll...}` use `{p{1cm}p{3em}p{40mm}...}` and to fix the width of the whole table read about the environments `tabular*`,`tabularx` and `tabulary`. If that is not enough, use a smaller font if needed, and if that is not enough, is time to redesign  (remove irrelevant columns, use shorter headers, round decimals, etc.)

Comment: [My table doesn't fit; what are my options?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/332902/134144) might be worth having a look at.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle and Fran thank you. Combined advises do the job.